# Sending basic authentication information via form

Tags: php, authentication, basic-authentication

I am working on a site that currently uses a basic authentication dialog box login system, that is the type of dialog that you get if you go here: http://www.dur.ac.uk/vm.boatclub/password/index.php
I did not set this system up and am not in a position to easily/quickly work around it, but it DOES work. The issue however is that the dialog box is not very helpful in telling you what login information you have to use (that is which username and password combination), and so I would like to replace it with a form. I had been thinking that this wasn't possible but I wanted to ask in order to find out.

Is it possible to set up an HTML form that sends the data to the server such that it accepts it in the same way that it would using this dialog box? Alternatively is it possible to set up a PHP script that would take normal form data and process it somehow passing it to the server such that it logs in?

Edit: After being told that this is basic authentication I went around and have managed to find a way that works and keeps the user persistently logged in. However, this does not work in internet explorer. The solution was simply to redirect the user to:
http://username:password@www.dur.ac.uk/vm.boatclub/password/index.php
But Internet Explorer removed it due to phishing uses about 3 years ago. Is there a way to use javascript to get the browser to access the site in this way? Or will I have to simply change my UI?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a fair bit of research I found a way that works in both Chrome and IE, that is all that I've tested it in, but the logic of the code does not suggest it should break anywhere. It is based upon this article:

http://www.peej.co.uk/articles/http-auth-with-html-forms.html

Which is rather in depth but the crux of it is this - on the form submit you make an AJAX request into the basic authenticated folder. AJAX requests can accept username and password information for basic auth, and once the browser has authed once it's authorised in that realm, i.e. it will stay logged in. The previous article does it in pure javascript, so to add something other than simply explaining the link here's a (hopefully fairly transparent) implementation using jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('#loginForm').submit(function()
    {
      var username = $('#usernameInput').val();
      var password = $('#passwordInput').val();

      $.ajax(
        {
          'password' : password,
          'username' : username,
          'url'      : 'http://www.website.com/basic-auth-file.php',
          'type'     : 'GET',
          'success'  : function(){ window.location = 'http://www.website.com/basic-auth-file.php'; },
          'error'    : function(){ alert('Bad Login Details');},
        }
      );

      return false;
    });
  });
```

This achieved what I wanted, and is relatively simple to understand, however I would implore anyone who wanted this to go out and didn't know about basic auth to go out and do the research!

Comment: I started on the site you referenced, above, and then found this post.  Code from the other site, you code, and the link in @alfred's answer all prompt me to enter credentials, on all browsers.  I need something that will work on an iPhone (which doesn't have curl), so my client has the option of allowing Safari to save the form fields.  Typing the user name and password is a real pain on the touch keyboard.

Comment: I don't really now how to reply, this honestly does work on my site. I suggest that you just ask a question yourself, with the specifics. Alfred's code is server side stuff, and it requires you to wrap every single page, and so isn't an optimum solution. My code also will only work once per session (as browsers forget basic auth information between sessions). I also know that this works on my iPhone! So please, ask a separate question with more details.

Answer (score 8):

You can replace it with a form. http://www.dur.ac.uk/vm.boatclub/password/index.php uses [basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

### basic access authentication

What you could do is perform basic authentication via curl

```
<?php 
// HTTP authentication 
$url = "http://www.dur.ac.uk/vm.boatclub/password/index.php"; 
$ch = curl_init();     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myusername:mypassword");  
$result = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);  
//echo $result; 
?>
```

### Option 1

Proxy everything just echo'ing `$result`

### Option 2

[Read headers](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-get-headers-sent-from-browser/) from `$result` and if status code != 200 then wrong login information has been entered. User should enter form again. If status code == 200 right credentials have been entered and you should do http basic authentication by sending headers.

```
header("Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username . ":" . $password);
```

You should not echo any data($result) before sending header else you will get an error

### Some quick links:

- http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html

Comment: This is reassuring that it exists so thankyou but I'm a bit confused on the implimentation side of things. The script here, where is this meant to be executed? Does this send the user and password information to the page given in "$url"? Is it then essentially a matter of header redirecting and you should be allowed straight in? 
Thanks!

Comment: this is POST from your form you want to create. myusername = $_POST['username'] && mypassword = $_POST['password']. Then you do basic auth

Comment: I've just looked it up and now I understand what's going on, as you've set RETURNTRANSFER then $result will contain the HTML from that page, which is then being echo'd. Is there a way to simply get to that page, maintaining being logged in? What's more whilst on that page the links would need to work and keep the user logged in.

Comment: My knowledge of these sort of interactions is quite limited so this is only my best guess but I believe the issue is that the browser isn't sending back the appropriate cookie when it visits a new link. When this "curled" page is accessed the browser recieves something that looks like a cookie in the header (I assume that's what Set-Cookie does) but it doesn't send it back upon clicking links. Can you make curl tell the browser to send the cookie with each new request?

Comment: @volatilestorm. Oops what I tought is not completely true. I will think about a little more and will get back to you. I think I have 2 solutions.