# HTTP Basic Auth - Server Says?

Tags: javascript, html, basic-authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending basic authentication information via form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460543/sending-basic-authentication-information-via-form)

When connecting to a web folder with basic auth the server can "say" something to you.

For example when you you try to access a restricted folder on example.com you get an alert box that says:

> The server http://domain.com requires a username and password. The
>   server says: **Hello**

Is there a way to see the response via javascript or html5? (in this case **hello**)

Comment: Make an ajax request then parse the `WWW-Authenticate` response header

Comment: How do you access the response header of a basic auth request like that?

Comment: I tried getResponseHeader but all the values are null

Answer (score 0):

Basic Auth I believe is only submittable via the browser's interface. To have a restricted access area the better thing to do is have a page that submits to the basic auth.

[Sending basic authentication information via form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460543/sending-basic-authentication-information-via-form)

I believe this should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried that but there was nothing on there about getting the message from the server?

Comment: fyi: I'm already able to submit basic auth using javascript. Just looking for the response of "Server says:"

Comment: the only way to do that is by submitting it through form or ajax which is how the answer to the other question i showed you. What do you mean by "getting the message from the server" if you are going to submit it via ajax the server's message to the client are going to be mostly ignored unless you care to get the page via ajax also and post this separately...

Comment: In my example above you can see the server responds with a message inside the header. (hello in the example)