# Rest API authentication - Further clarification

Tags: api, rest, authentication, cookies, http-authentication

I've been reading up on a lot of the REST API authentication threads, trying to piece together how it all works.
There seem to be 2 main camps, the 'just use HTTP basic/digest authentication and their associated HTTP headers, send user password every time' and the 'authenticate once against a URL, get a token, store it, then send that with each request.' Everyone agrees not to use sessions and to use HTTPS, fair enough.

I simply want users on a browser once they log in to be authenticated and not have to authenticate separately to an API. Mostly I want my webservice to be free access for searches and such, and only need authentication for create/edit/delete operations in some locations. The front end is just a user's browser, the service gets called via ajax calls.

My questions are:

1. If you already use forms authentication on your site how do you best set the HTTP authentication headers as well? Do you need to tag on a bit of jQuery (like this accepted answer [Sending basic authentication information via form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460543/sending-basic-authentication-information-via-form)) to your login form so you authenticate to the API as well and store the, i.e. set up a /api/authenticate section that basically just checks your HTTP authentication details so they get stored by your browser.
2. If you get back a token and send that instead of your user/pass every request where do you store it? Everyone says not to use cookies, but where else is a browser can you store something like that? I can understand on a smart device where you have a keyring or in an application where it's got somewhere to store it, but not in a browser

Other options I've seen are to, I think, basically write your web app and have that send off the requests to the API on the users behalf (so you authenticate normally with forms, then the web app does the API calls, sending user credentials itself, which can be stored) instead of coming from the user directly. This just seems like a whole lot of extra work to get around the problem, which would neatly be circumvented with a session if one decided to not be entirely RESTful, and you also have to store authentication details.

Am I better off just not bothering being totally restful as it doesn't really suit this purpose and using a session? It seems so much easier.