# Use HTTP-AUTH to redirect?

Tags: php, http, curl

Is there a way to have PHP redirect to a new page, and pass along HTTP-AUTH?

I have been using cURL, as the second example here:
[Sending basic authentication information via form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460543/sending-basic-authentication-information-via-form#)

Unfortunately, when I do this, the actual URL (as displayed in the browser URL bar) remains the originating PHP's URL, not the target that I'm browsing.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
<?php

$user = "xyz";
$pass = "abc";
$userpass = $user . ":" . $pass;

$url = "http://website/directory/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpass);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if($httpcode == 200){
    header("Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($userpass));
    echo $result;
}else{
    header("Location: http://website/login.php");
}

?>
```

I have also tried replacing the tail end of the above:

```
if($httpcode == 200){
    header("Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($userpass));
    header("Location: http://website/directory/");
}else{
    header("Location: http://website/login.php");
}
```

But that fails; it redirects to http://website.xyz/directory, but it does not pass in the user/pass, and I am presented with a login from the server upon arrival.

Technically, the following works.  However, I'd much prefer a more graceful solution than passing user/pass inside the HREF:

```
header("Location: http://" . $userpass . "website/directory/");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to pass the Authentication along with the url. Like this:

```
header('Location: http://username:password@website/directory/');
```

As base64 is insecure like plain text, it shouldn't be an additional security risk. Browsers will not display the user:pass related part of the url in address bar. But the browser will display a message box (or something else) to let you confirm that you are about to login to this site using username: yourusername

Comment: I thought of that, too.  It does not seem to actually pass the HTTP-AUTH to the new page when it is redirected;  I am still prompted by the webserver for user/pass upon arriving at the new location.

Comment: Are you sure that the website you are redirecting to is accepting your credentials? I've tested it on localhost with two different folders, and it worked

Comment: I you look at my code above, and replace "echo $result;" with "header('Location: http://website/directory');", that is what I have tried.  It failed.  Upon arriving at http://website/directory/, I was presented with a login prompt.

Comment: I am new to this site, and finding the comment section's limitations frustrating.  The "website/directory" actually has an http in front of it.  Apologies if it looks different than I typed it.

Comment: Use backticks to escape `http://server.com/script.php` if you want to display them in comments. Also there is a help button ;)

Comment: The horribly poor design on the comments here is off-topic.  Sorry.  Didn't mean to get into that.  Back to on-topic:  Your suggestion does not work for me.  Is there something I can check with phpinfo() that needs to be set for it to work?  Otherwise...  thanks, but ...  next idea?

Comment: Seems that my test environment wasn't working as expected. Therefore my first answer. Check my update.

Comment: Thanks hek2mgl.  Technically, that works.  However, I'd still like a more graceful solution, if possible.

Comment: There is not a more *graceful* solution. Think a moment and decide if you want to live in a digital world where it would be possible more graceful. A world full of cross site scripting..... However, you should try Internet Explorer ;)

Comment: Try "IE"... that wasn't nice.  Why not just insult my mother?  Actually... as much as it pains me to say, IE10 isn't that bad.  I still stay away because of its history with security holes... but it's hard to believe this browser is from the same company that brought us IE6

Comment: It was a joke. What makes my answer less correct? (You've decided to unaccept it)

Answer (score 1):

An explanation of the issue you're having: The `Authorization` header is only valid in HTTP requests. It has no meaning in a HTTP response, like where you're putting it, and thus browsers are ignoring it.

The solution you've been given (passing the username and password in the URL) is as good as you're going to get. There's no alternative available.