# PHP support for HTTPRequest or curl

Tags: php, curl

Running PHP version: 5.5.9-1 on ubuntu 4.22
phpinfo() here
https://www.gstream.org/api/v2/appnuance2.php

HTTPRequest and curl are failing ...

Thanks in Advance! 
Happy New Year!

Failing means that all the console messages are displayed to the point where the function fails and then in the php tradition - nothing :-)

I have been attempting to use HTTPRequest and/or curl to make requests to a web service. In both cases below where the object is initialized the php script will fail. I have been reading about HTTPRequest and curl support in PHP 5.5.9 - seems like it should be there.

The sample code below will fail at curl_init()

```
/*
 * This function executes the HTTP GET Request for us
 *
 * The HTTP response will be returned to the calling routine
 *
 */
function executeTtsRequest($url)
{
    printf("Inside executeTtsRequest() <br />");
    printf("testing curl <br />");
    printf("url: %s<br />", $url);

    // create curl resource
    printf("Calling curl_init <br />");
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set url
    printf("Calling curl_setopt <br />");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");

    //return the transfer as a string
    printf("Calling curl_setopt <br />");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // $output contains the output string
    printf("Calling curl_exec <br />");
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

The code below will fail at new HttpRequest()

```
/*
 * This function executes the HTTP GET Request for us
 *
 * The HTTP response will be returned to the calling routine
 *
 */
function executeTtsRequest_hold($url)
{

    printf("Inside executeTtsRequest() <br />");
    printf("url: %s<br />", $url);


    printf("Create the HttpRequest object <br />");
    $r = new HttpRequest($url, HttpRequest::METH_GET);

    printf("********************************** <br />");
    printf("We never get here !!! <br />");

    try
    {
        printf("Calling r->send() <br />");
        $m = $r->send();
        return $m;
    }
    catch (HttpException $ex)
    {
        printf("Handle HttpException <br />");
        echo $ex;
    }
}
```

Thanks again
Happy New year!

Comment: PHP 5.5 support ended July 10, 2016

Comment: Might have ended, but this has worked since 2010 and before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460543/sending-basic-authentication-information-via-form

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment, but I think you're going to need to consult the PHP error log. I don't think anyone can tell you what is wrong based on the information currently available. Also, I don't think you actually asked a question, but I think the"why is it failing?" is implied.

Comment: Probably need to check php -i ,then follow the logs that it references. Check the system log. Check in php -i that php was compiled with --with-curl (Configure Command)

Comment: TRUE - thanks - I'll looking closer --> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'HttpRequest' not found in /var/www/gstream.org/public_html/api/v2/nmdpTtsHttpClient-public.php
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /var/www/gstream.org/public_html/api/v2/nmdpTtsHttpClient-public.php